# Prove that if $H \cong \mathbb Z$ or $H \cong \mathbb Z_n$ then $H = ⟨g⟩$ for some $g ∈ G$.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm studying for my final and I came across this homework problem that I had previously done but I don't remember how to do it anymore.  It is as follows ($G, H$ are groups):

Suppose that $H \le  G$. Prove that if $H \cong \mathbb Z$ or $H \cong \mathbb Z_n$ then $H = ⟨g⟩$ for some $g ∈ G$.

1) So is it basically saying that if $H \cong \mathbb Z_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$, then $H$ is a cyclic subgroup of another group?

2) How would I go about proving this?  I believe it intuitively because for any $\mathbb Z_n$, we can always for say $H = ⟨1⟩$ for modular addition.

Answer (score 2):

If $\phi: \mathbb Z \to H$ is an isomorphism, then $H = \langle \phi(1) \rangle$.

If $\phi: \mathbb Z_n \to H$ is an isomorphism, then $H = \langle \phi(\bar 1) \rangle$.

Comment: What does the line above the 1 mean?

Comment: $\bar 1$ is the class of $1$ in $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: @User123454321 Elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are equivalence classes of elements of $\mathbb{Z}$. Two elements $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ are equivalent if their difference is divisible by $n$. So for example if $n=2$, then the equivalence class of $1$ is the set $\{...,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,7,...\}$